# What is a functional model, sequential model, and concurrent model?

Tags: math, computer-science, computation-theory

I’m doing research on the models of computation and how they work and what they are. I would like someone   To help me understand what these are and help me find books or anything to research them.

I’m trying to learn how models of computation work, I’m trying to find research and ways to learn as well.

Comment: http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~tinelli/classes/4980/Spring20/notes/chap2a.pdf

Comment: There's the wikipedia page for [Model of Computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation), which breaks down the three types into various examples. Overall the question is very broad (and covers a very abstract topic): is there something more specific you're interested in or are confused about?

Comment: Yeah they classify each of the models but don’t provide a definition on what the it means like I don’t get what a concurrent model or functional model is.

Comment: Hey Dave where do you find this information online. I think it’s very helpful

Comment: Just as my own words: A concurrent model would be a computational model for concurrent programming (again, a bit self-defining and broad). In essence, this would be to model distributed processes or algorithms over several potential computational nodes or machines. A sequential model is our more traditional computer: it takes some input, uses memory, and produces an output, possibly in guaranteed finite time. A functional model is more aligned to something like LISP/LINQ/lambda calc, which while we can run on a sequential model, are more easily "modelled" in their own respective dialogue.